# Map the object with different getter name

Tags: mapstruct

I would like to map the source object to target but in my model I m using the different naming convention for getters

```
//instead of getName()
String name() { return name;}
```

is it any option to configure mapstruct to use my naming strategy

Comment: I ve just found the response: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-spi-accessor-naming/spi-impl/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/spi/CustomAccessorNamingStrategy.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use different naming convention for getters a custom `AccessorNamingStrategy` should be implemented.

The best approach would be to extend the [`DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy`](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/ap/spi/DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy.java) and override the `isGetterMethod`.

Really important is to make sure that you are really returning something only for getters. Otherwise methods like `toString` would also be considered as getters

Comment: I can see. I used this approach, but I was sure that it would be some easier way to integrate (flag, property or something) My "getters" are generated by lombok -> it some kind of standard.

Comment: You don't have to create fluent getters by lombok. You can create normal Java Bean style getters. The problem with Fluent getters is that every single method that returns something would be considered as a getter and this is something that we can't solve by default. This can only be done when you know your code and classes and you can write a custom `AccessorNamingStrategy`. If you think that there is some way that we can do it in a standard way feel free to propose it

Comment: "You don't have to create fluent getters by lombok." -> well actually I ve to -> it s a company standard :)